# HorizontalScrollView stay on top

Tags: android, xml, toolbar, horizontalscrollview

I have activity with horizontal scroll view to display four button's. Below located FrameLayout witch display fragment based on what button was clicked. Second and Fourth button shows RecyclerView with a lot of data. How can i make this horizontal scroll view to stay on top below or in place of Toolbar, so i can switch between fragments withount going all the way up?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/smoky_white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".o_kaznau">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:title="О КазНАИУ" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/im_maincorpus1"/>

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/about_btn"
                        android:onClick="aboutAbout"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:text="Об университете" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnRyk"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/about_btn"
                        android:onClick="aboutRyc"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:text="Руководство" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnPolitika"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/about_btn"
                        android:onClick="aboutPolitika"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:text="Политика" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/about_btn"
                        android:onClick="aboutYstav"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:text="Устав" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/aboutFL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you give image description ?

Comment: Try giving `R.id.aboutFL` as the `container` whilst doing fragment transactions